# dynamic sumif with date in Google Sheets

Tags: date, dynamic, sum, google-sheets-formula

This code works `=sumif(Expenses!C$3:C,"<1/1/2022",Expenses!B$3:B)`. It returns the correct value of 1,186. Column C contains dates in dd/mm/yyyy format.

**Instead of "hard coding" a specific date**, I want to be able to input a YEAR into a cell.  But, this does not work: `=sumif(Expenses!C$3:C,"<"&A4,Expenses!B$3:B)` (where I input the year only (e.g., 2022) into cell A4. (There are no records before 2021.)

Just for experimenting, this also does not work: `=sumif(Expenses!C$3:C,"<2022",Expenses!B$3:B)`.  It returns 0 - not the correct result. Likewise, this does not work: `=sumif(Expenses!C$3:C,"=2021",Expenses!B$3:B)`. It also returns 0.

FWIW, this also does not work: `=sumif(Expenses!C$3:C,"<=1/1/2022",Expenses!B$3:B)` (The first formula above at the beginning of this post returns 1,186 which is correct; this formula returns 0.

I have also used variations which cast the date as a year only and they do not work either. For example, `=sumif(YEAR(Expenses!C$3:C),"<"&A4,Expenses!B$3:B)`. This returns 0 - incorrect (for A4 = 2022).

How can I modify the first formula to alter the sum based on the year?

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=sumif(arrayformula(year(Expenses!C3:C)),"<"&A4,Expenses!B3:B)
```